# writing text file with line breaks

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a text file where many lines are created, so I want to know how to put each value on a new line.

this is my code:

```
import itertools
from itertools import permutations , combinations
lista=[]

splits=itertools.permutations('0123456789', 5)
for x in splits:
    lista.append(x)

f=open('lala.txt', 'w')
for i in lista:
    f.write(str(i))
```

in this part I need to put the line break: `f.write(str(i))`

I have tried with: `f.write(str(i)\n)` but gives me an error

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use:

`f.write(str(i) + '\n')`

Answer (score 3):

Since your lines are already in a list, you can use `writelines()`:

```
import itertools

lista = [",".join(i)+'\n' for i in itertools.permutations('0123456789',5)]

with open('lala.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lista)
```

I've used the [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) which will automatically close the file for you; and used a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) to create your initial list of permutations.

Answer (score 1):

Editing the list itself might be undesirable. In such cases, you could `csv` module:

```python
import itertools, os, csv

lista = list(itertools.permutations('0123456789',5))

with open('lala.txt', 'w', newline=os.linesep) as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerows(lista)
```

The `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` is to remove the `"` marks presented because the permuted items are strings.